Default behaviour of bezel scrolling a ScrollView in Android Wear OS in Java not happening
As best as I understand it, the bezel on a Wear OS device, like a Samsung Watch6, should scroll a ScrollView by default.  In this XML layout the tvRules text does not scroll when the bezel is turned.
<androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backdrop"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/DotDashTheme">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:shadowColor="#ff0000"
        android:shadowDx="2"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="@string/rules"
        android:textColor="#aa0000"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svRules"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bBack"
        android:layout_below="@id/lTitle"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRules"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/rules_how_to_play"
            android:textColor="#1010D0"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_button"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/bBack"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>

I can force it in Java code with the following: -
//In activity onCreate()
ScrollView svRules = findViewById(R.id.svRules);
TextView tvRules = findViewById(R.id.tvRules);
svRules.post(() -> svRules.smoothScrollTo(0, tvRules.getTop()));
svRules.requestFocus();
svRules.setOnGenericMotionListener((v, event) -> {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL && event.isFromSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_ROTARY_ENCODER)) {
    float delta = -event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_SCROLL) * ViewConfiguration.get(Rules.this).getScaledVerticalScrollFactor();
    svRules.scrollBy(0, (int) delta);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

But I would much prefer to know why it does not happen automatically?
My project gradle has: -
dependencies {
  implementation libs.appcompat
  implementation libs.material
  implementation libs.wear
  implementation libs.core
}

And libs.versions.toml: -
[versions]
appcompat = "1.7.0"
material = "1.12.0"
wear = "1.3.0"
core = "1.13.1"

[libraries]
appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
wear = { group = "androidx.wear", name = "wear", version.ref = "wear" }
core = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core", version.ref = "core" }

Is coding in Java the way to go, or have I missed something in my setup?

The view must be focused in order for the rotary bezel to work, however, after a certain version of android, focus is no applied automatically, as it is described here (Rotary input).
You can add focus using xml, add the values to you scrollview (so it can be focusable):
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

And inside it add (to add the focus to it):
<requestFocus/>
Like this:
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svRules"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bBack"
        android:layout_below="@id/lTitle"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <requestFocus/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRules"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/rules_how_to_play"
            android:textColor="#1010D0"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>
    </ScrollView>

OR
You can just request the focus using code (which you already are):
ScrollView svRules = findViewById(R.id.svRules);
svRules.requestFocus();


Thank you for replying. I should have stated I spent a couple of days on this, read all the articles, tried some github resources (but none in Java, all Kotlin), worked with several different AIs.  In short I did try those properties in my layout, and many others - also trying setting focus to the scrollview, the textview, and denied focus to the same and others, trying every single variation.  Whilst I agree your answer is correct by theory, sadly such is not the case in practice.  Though happy to be proven wrong!
